# Linux-Windows cross-platform custom folder icons (Mac would be a bonus)

Tags: linux, windows, icons, cross-platform, appearance

I would like a few fancy icons for my USB drives and external drives, and I use both Linux and Windows.

The problem is, the way they assign an icon to a folder seems incompatible.

On Linux, changing the icon creates a hidden file within the directory, `.directory`, that contains something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=/run/media/myuser/mydrivelabel/path/to/icon.ico
```

I forgot to emphasise that since I want my icons on any computer, they have to be physically on the drive. The above path is absolute but I didn't find a way around that yet, and it's not too much of a problem because there is no such thing as "randomly changing drive letters" on Linux.

However, on Windows, I generate a `desktop.ini` system file with something like:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=..\icons\myicon.ico,0
```

Both work fine individually (on the corresponding OS) but even though it seems that modifying `desktop.ini` doesn't affect the icon being well displayed on Linux, the fact that I choose the icon in Linux (en therefore create the `.directory` file) seems to reset the icon settings on Windows. Worse, it seems that as long as I have this Linux file in my directory, the `desktop.ini` will be ignored and I won't be able to change the icon that way in Windows.

As always I never know if this is the right "stack-forum" to ask my question, so kindly redirect me to the right place if my post is not where it should be.